# How to duplicate content control in word document c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, openxml, contentcontrol

I am trying to duplicate content controls, each content control will have the same format/style etc but populated with different data.

At the moment i have one content control, is there a way to actually duplicate this content control lets say in the next paragraph and populate them with different data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way i was able to do it was using tables inside content control instead, you find the content control using its tag, and find the table inside this content control, then you can copy this table, add rows etc..